# Amp analytics encodeURIComponent for tracking pixel

Tags: amp-html, accelerated-mobile-page, amp-analytics

I have an amp page that I would like to track with our analytics tool.

The non amp implementation for the tracking pixel is something like this e.g.

```
var payload = {a:1,b2}
var img = document.createElement("img");

img.src = "http://www.examplepixel.com?data=" + encodeURIComponent(payload)
```

I have read the documentation on amp-pixel and amp-analytics I see no way to perform the encoding.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

The amp way is using amp-pixel:

```
<amp-pixel src="http://www.examplepixel.com?data=%7Ba%3A1%2Cb%3A%202%7D"
layout="nodisplay"></amp-pixel>
```

Comment: But how do I create a javascript object, encode it, and add it to the query string - client side

Comment: Custom JS does not work in AMP, you have to manually encode all relevant parameters into the URL (as I've showed in my sample).